# Как правильно развернуть окружение разработчика?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, pdo, xampp

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на своем примере, как развернуть:

- XAMPP (или другой виртуальный сервер) проблемы с правами
- Workbench (или другое приложение для MySQL) проблемы с правами или драйверами.
- PHPStorm (установился нормально)
- Zend Framework 2 (доктрина ругалась на PDO адаптер)

Пересел с Винды на Linux Ubuntu 14.04. который раз пытаюсь - не получается. В основном проблемы с правами к Localhost и мн.др

Есть ли свежая пошаговая инструкция?

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнём с

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Установим Apache

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Установим MySQL

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

Активация MySQL

```
sudo mysql_install_db
```

Завершаем установку MySQL следующим скриптом

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Программа вас попросит ввести пароль БД, вводите. Затем он задаст несколько вопросов. Отвечайте, как указано ниже

```
Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] y                                            
 ... Success!

Normally, root should only be allowed to connect from 'localhost'.  This
ensures that someone cannot guess at the root password from the network.

Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n] y
... Success!

By default, MySQL comes with a database named 'test' that anyone can
access.  This is also intended only for testing, and should be removed
before moving into a production environment.

Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n] y
 - Dropping test database...
 ... Success!
 - Removing privileges on test database...
 ... Success!

Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes made so far
will take effect immediately.

Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n] y
 ... Success!

Cleaning up...
```

Установим PHP

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

Перезагрузим Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Всё, теперь по адресу `localhost/index.html` должно появиться приветствие. 
Корневая директория - `/var/www/html`

Оригинал: [How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Данное руководство от "May 31, 2012"

Comment: @Drakulitka, Тем не менее, оно работает, как часы.

Comment: а XAMPP не проще запускать/отключать ?

Comment: @Drakulitka, Вы и здесь можете легко выключать и включать сервисы.
`sudo service apache2 stop` -- для Apache. Для MySQL `sudo service mysql stop`

Comment: А если хотите ещё проще, то запишите эти строки в sh файл, сохраните на рабочий стол и запускайте двойным щелчком.

Comment: Пожалуй Вы меня уговорили, буду пробовать.
Спасибо.

отпишусь...

Comment: А как добавить хосты в var/www 
где их прописывать? или можно переадресовать?

Comment: О каких хостах вы говорите?

Comment: предпологается работать с несколькими сайтами, не только с var/www/html ну например еще var/www/domain.loc,  var/www/domain2.loc ... 
создал соответствующие папки в var/www но с них перебрасывает на var/www/html

Comment: @Drakulitka, создав папку "xyz", вы должны работать по ссылке `localhost/xyz`

Comment: Про виртуальные хосты красиво написано здесь:
[How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, получил то что хотел! +++++++